# nodejs storing session in separate dbs

Tags: node.js

I have nodejs application with express. I store my session in mongodb. But also I store application data that I store in the same db. Should I create another mongodb database for a sessions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same database, but have different collections (a collection in MongoDB is somehow similar with what MySQL calls table). That would be ok too.

Comment: alessioalex Thank you for the response. But if my data is very big and I have to use sharding?

Comment: if you have to use sharing then you'll need to scale out of just one box, gets more complicated.